# Skewed Window Function & Hive Source Partitions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, time-series

The data I am reading via Spark is highly skewed Hive Table with the following stats.

***(MIN, 25TH, MEDIAN, 75TH, MAX)*** via Spark UI:

`1506.0 B / 0 232.4 KB / 27288    247.3 KB / 29025    371.0 KB / 42669    269.0 MB / 27197137`

I believe it is causing problems downstream in the job when I perform some `Window Funcs`, and `Pivots`.

I tried exploring this parameter to limit the partition size however nothing changed and the partitions are still skewed upon read.

`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes")`

Also, when I cache this DF with the Hive table as source it takes a few min and even causes some GC in the Spark UI most likely because of the skew as well.

***Does this `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` work on Hive tables or only files?***

***What is the best course of action for handling this skewed Hive source?***

***Would something like a stage barrier write to parquet or Salting be suitable for this problem?***

I would like to avoid `.repartition()` on read as it adds another layer to an already data roller-coaster of a job.

Thank you

==================================================

After further research it appears the `Window Function` is causing skewed data too and this is where the `Spark Job` hangs.

I am performing some `time series` filling via double `Window Function` (forward then backward fill to impute all the `null` sensor readings) and am trying to follow this article to try a `salt` method to evenly distribute ... however the following code produces all `null` values so the `salt` method is not working.

Not sure why I am getting `skews` after `Window` since each measure item I am partitioning by has roughly the same amount of records after checking via `.groupBy()` ... thus why would `salt` be needed?

```py
+--------------------+-------+
|          measure   |  count|
+--------------------+-------+
|    v1              |5030265|
|      v2            |5009780|
|     v3             |5030526|
| v4                 |5030504|
...
```

salt post => https://medium.com/appsflyer/salting-your-spark-to-scale-e6f1c87dd18

```py
nSaltBins = 300 # based off number of "measure" values
df_fill = df_fill.withColumn("salt", (F.rand() * nSaltBins).cast("int"))

# FILLS [FORWARD + BACKWARD]
window = Window.partitionBy('measure')\
               .orderBy('measure', 'date')\
               .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

# FORWARD FILLING IMPUTER
ffill_imputer = F.last(df_fill['new_value'], ignorenulls=True)\
.over(window)
fill_measure_DF = df_fill.withColumn('value_impute_temp', ffill_imputer)\
.drop("value", "new_value")

window = Window.partitionBy('measure')\
               .orderBy('measure', 'date')\
               .rowsBetween(0,Window.unboundedFollowing)

# BACKWARD FILLING IMPUTER
bfill_imputer = F.first(df_fill['value_impute_temp'], ignorenulls=True)\
.over(window)
df_fill = df_fill.withColumn('value_impute_final', bfill_imputer)\
.drop("value_impute_temp")
```

Comment: _I believe it is causing problems downstream in the job when I perform some Window Funcs, and Pivots_ - that's unlikely. With higher probability the window functions and pivots are the ones that cause the performance issues, as both are *very* expensive. However without knowing more about the table properties and execution plan it is impossible to say for sure.

Comment: possibly ... but the problem is on the final ```write``` that has the bundled ```rdd``` of ```skewed input, window, and pivot transformations``` for a specific stage where all of the data is in 1 partition and the remaining partitions are empty thus the job just hangs.

Comment: I doubt all understand barrier either. But the point is there is too little to go by in your prose.

Comment: @thePurplePython. Could you please share some code n table structure?

Comment: Here's a link with some great explanation for handling skew in hive.. may be you get some help https://medium.com/hotels-com-technology/skew-join-optimization-in-hive-b66a1f4cc6ba

Comment: @vikrantrana thank you but am using spark as processing engine not hive ... will try to share something ... the skewed source is a problem but the root cause seems to be the window function with skewed partitions ... dealing with time series data here too ... am trying a ```salt``` method

Comment: @thePurplePython- ok.p please share your findings once you get something. Thanks ☺️

Comment: ok ... i added more explanation / troubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

Salting might be helpful in the case where a single partition is big enough to not fit in memory on a single executor. This might happen even if all the keys are equally distributed as well (as in your case).

You have to include the salt column in your partitionBy clause which you are using to create the Window.

```
window = Window.partitionBy('measure', 'salt')\
               .orderBy('measure', 'date')\
               .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
```

Again you have to create another window which will operate on the intermediate result

```
window1 = Window.partitionBy('measure')\
                   .orderBy('measure', 'date')\
                   .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
```

Comment: do you have a minimal example of creating the salt column? something like: `window1.withColumn("salt", rand(100))`

Answer (score 1):

[Hive based solution :](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)

You can enable Skew join optimization using hive configuration. Applicable settings are:

```
set hive.optimize.skewjoin=true;
set hive.skewjoin.key=500000;
set hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.map.tasks=10000;
set hive.skewjoin.mapjoin.min.split=33554432;
```

See databricks tips for this :

skew [hints](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/join-performance/skew-join.html) may work in this case

Comment: Skew hint is a proprietary Databricks extension, isn't it? And if I am not mistaken Hive skew options are ignored by Spark.

Comment: yes this capability is specific to databricks and has not been released for open source spark

Comment: we shouldn't accept an answer that only paying users of databricks can use